# How to change types of a class that extends another class with an interface

Tags: typescript, inheritance, types, pixi.js, eventemitter

I have a class `Sprite` that extends from another class that comes from a library, its name is `PIXI.Sprite`, it extends from the `PIXI.utils.EventEmitter` class but the names of the events, etc are not strictly typed, so I've created my own implementation of this class via a custom class `EventEmitter` extending `PIXI.utils.EventEmitter` that waits for a record of `eventName: [...types]` in a Generic argument.

But since we can't extend from two classes, and the `on`, `once`, `emits`... methods are not well-typed, I need a way to change their types, I tried via an interface that extends my `EventEmitter` class, but it doesn't work.

Here are my classes :

```
import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js';

export type EventList = Record<string, any[]>;

export class EventEmitter<Events extends EventList> extends PIXI.utils.EventEmitter {
    public emit<K extends (keyof Events) & string>(event: K, ...args: Events[K]): boolean {
        return super.emit(event, ...args);
    }

    public on<K extends (keyof Events) & string>(event: K, fn: (...params: Events[K]) => void, context?: any): this {
        return super.on(event, fn as (...args: any[]) => void, context);
    }

    public once<K extends (keyof Events) & string>(event: K, fn: (...params: Events[K]) => void, context?: any): this {
        return super.once(event, fn as (...args: any[]) => void, context);
    }
}

export interface IEventEmitter<Events extends EventList> extends EventEmitter {
    emit<K extends (keyof Events) & string>(event: K, ...args: Events[K]): boolean;
    on<K extends (keyof Events) & string>(event: K, fn: (...params: Events[K]) => void, context?: any): this;
    once<K extends (keyof Events) & string>(event: K, fn: (...params: Events[K]) => void, context?: any): this

}

export type SpriteEvents = {
    click: [event: PIXI.InteractionEvent];
}


export class Sprite extends PIXI.Sprite implents IEventEmitter<SpriteEvents> {
    // some code.
}

const a = new Sprite();
```

When I type `a.on('`, it should only suggest me `click` but no, when I hover it, it says that the method has the types of the `PIXI.Sprite.prototype.on` method, not the one from the interface.

How can I have my methods properly typed without copying the code from my `EventEmitter` class (which indeed corrects the problem but is dirty) ?